# Does the Canon MF Scan Utility Support scanning multi page pdfs?

Tags: scanner, multi-function-printer

Is it possible to scan multi-page pdfs with the Windows Canon MF Scan Utility and a Cannon imageCLASS mf244dw all-in-one?  If so how?

Comment: Multi-page PDFs are automatic as far as I know. If you stick a stack of papers in the ADF it will scan them all in to a single PDF. If you are scanning from glass, you are prompted after each page if that is the end or if you want to scan more. At least that's how my Canon works.

Comment: @Appleoddity okay, that helped, I think the issue is that the two-sided pages I have are scanned and not one sided pages...sorry I was looking for a setting.  So single sided pages, use the feeder, and double sided pages use the glass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use the document feeder to scan multiple documents, but it is not capable of duplex (two-sided) scanning. So, you have to scan the opposite side separately.

[imageCLASS MF244dw Specifications](http://www.canon.ca/inetCA/en/serviceDetail?m=load&directLink=Y&mid=1418C021&type=D&opt=1)

Comment: I know that you can scan only one side at a time, but the issue is scanning more than one side into a document.  (I might not have been clear enough on that).  The imageCLASS MF244dw does prompt you (on it's onboard display) to scan another page, but only if you are using the flatbed scanner, not if you are using the feeder.  So if you're using a two-sided page you can only use the glass bed, and that's where I got mixed up.

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place the first page of the document you wish to scan on the bed; and do not use the document feeder.
2. Press the physical `Scan->PC` button on the right hand side of the printer.
3. After it's done scanning, press the physical `OK` button.
4. A menu screen on the printer will appear which reads `Scan Next. Press Start` (this is prompting you to scan another page)
5. Place the second page in the document scanner.
6. Press the start button.
7. Repeat steps 4-7 until all the pages you want scanned in the document have been scanned.
8. When complete from the `Scan Next. Press Start` menu, using the arrows select `<Finish Scanning>`.
9. Now there will be a single scanned PDF (if settings are correct) with all the pages you scanned in your documents folder.